# Is virtuoso-t restarting indexing after every boot?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, indexing

`virtuoso-t` is indexing my files **again**, which takes a massively long time with all my CD's ripped to flac and converted to mp3 and ogg, not to mention all other files on the system.

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  P COMMAND
3416 jhendrix  39  19  508m 142m 5060 R 99.1  1.8  47:10.40 1 virtuoso-t
```

Why is it indexing all files again? My PC sounds like a vacuum cleaner right now. I know I can kill the process, but I want to know why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As for my experiene - virtuoso-t takes so much cpu only until it index all the files. Once it happened - it behaves calmly. I suggest You to leave Your computer turned on for the night.

Also You might control the memory used by virtuoso-t.

And finally You coould have it broken. I suggest You remove Your local database then (it has some confings - and maybe they have gone made). For that I'd suggest You to remove all nepomuk related folders in `~/.kde`.

Comment: it was indexing for over a week ... 24x7 and once it stopped and I rebooted a couple of days later it started all over again. So I killed it all together.